# Incompatible dimensions for vector multiplication (3dfim+ (afni))

Tags: vector, time-series

I am trying to run 3dfim+ to calculate a correlation map for a region of interest. I de-obliqued the data (the functional and the ROI mask which was converted to the same functional space) with `3drefit -deoblique` (because I was getting an error message about data being oblique). However the de-obliqued functional image now doesn't have the time dimension and the 1D file I'm getting when extracting timeseries from a ROI mask applied to this functional only has one number in it (884.727 [264 voxels]). Isn't it supposed to be a column of averaged voxel intensities in this ROI for each time point? Where did all the volumes go? When I try to run 3dfim+ I receive the following error:

> Matrix error: Incompatible dimensions for vector multiplication: 0x0 X 1 ** Memory usage: chunks=84 bytes=621942 Standard error: ++ 3dfim+: AFNI version=AFNI_2011_05_26_1457 (Jun 22 2011) [64-bit] ++ Authored by: B. Douglas Ward 3dfim+ main Return code: 1 Interface Fim failed to run.

The command I try to run is

```
3dfim+ -input /path/mcorr_001_brain_3drefit.nii.gz -ideal_file /path/mcorr_001_brain_3drefit_maskave.1D -out Correlation -bucket corr_map.nii.gz
```

I tried to run the same but with the original oblique data and additional to the standard:

> "WARNING: If you are performing spatial transformations on an oblique dset, such as /path/roi_sphere_30_21_18_flirt.nii.gz,or viewing/combining it with volumes of differing obliquity, you should consider running: 3dWarp -deoblique on this and other oblique datasets in the same session. "

There is still the error of "Matrix error: Incompatible dimensions for vector multiplication: 0x0 X 1" so it doesn't seem that deobliquing caused this problem!

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this problem?

Comment: Just an update: tried to run the same but with the original oblique data and additional to the standard                                           "WARNING:  If you are performing spatial transformations on an oblique dset, such as /path/roi_sphere_30_21_18_flirt.nii.gz,or viewing/combining it with volumes of differing obliquity, you should consider running: 3dWarp -deoblique on this and  other oblique datasets in the same session. "

there is still the error of   "Matrix error: Incompatible dimensions for vector multiplication: 0x0 X 1"

so it doesn't seem that deobliquing caused this problem!

Answer (score 0):

check your input file (mcorr_001_brain_3drefit.nii.gz) with 3dinfo to see if it has a time axis (TR information). If not simply add a time axis with 3drefit.